# Accessing global $foo inside a function

Tags: php

I'm trying to access `global $foo` inside a function, but it wont work. I don't want to add it when calling the function. Whats a good way to do this?

```
global $foo;
$foo = 'norman';

function kit($name)
{
if($foo == $name){echo 'Works';}else{echo 'Does not work';}
}

kit('norman')
```

Comment: I guess you forgot to read [the documentation on globals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). That's too bad, because all the answers are there. What prevented you from reading the documentation?

Answer (score 3):

You need to "import" into the local function scope by declaring it as global *inside* the function:

```
function kit($name)
{
    global $foo;
    if($foo == $name){echo 'Works';}else{echo 'Does not work';}
}
```

You can safely remove the global modifier from otuside the function.

Comment: global $foo is set in a diff page. So I do global $foo inside the function again?

Comment: If by page you mean file then no. Included files always inherit the global scope. You only need to do `global $foo` inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

A global variable declared outside function cannot be accessed inside the function try declaring global iinside the function itself.

Change it to this

```
function kit($name)
{
    global $foo;
    if($foo == $name){echo 'Works';}else{echo 'Does not work';}
}
```

Comment: You need to add global variable into the function.

Comment: This is telling the kit function to use the global version of the $foo variable, without global $foo; being specified inside each function you want to use it in, then it will create it's own local version of that variable

Comment: Cool. Just one thing. `global $foo` is declared in different page (where session variables are set), which is included in the page containing function kit. After it's been declared on that page, I need to declare it again inside the function? That's how it goes?

Comment: @Anigl Your comment came in after I posted mu question :-)